# Cakephp 3 redirect controller

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-3.0

In my CakePHP 3 application, after a controller redirect I get this error:

```
Error: [LogicException] Controller action can only return an instance of Response
Request URL: /mycontroller/
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\SigninsController))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#2 {main}
```

Regarding to CakePHP 2 [controller documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#flow-control) redirect was like this:

```
$this->redirect('/orders/thanks');
$this->redirect('http://www.example.com');
return $this->redirect(
        array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'confirm')
    );
```

But in CakePHP 3 [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::redirect) it seems like this:

```
return $this->redirect('/orders/thanks');
return $this->redirect('http://www.example.com');
return $this->redirect(
            ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'thanks']
        );
```

When I add `return` word before `$this->redirect`, error is solved. So does this makes problem ? Because I couldn't see a return redirect part in [cakephp 3 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html). Migration guide only mentions that third parameter is dropped.

Comment: Quoting the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#id2): "The method can no longer send response and exit script, instead it returns a Response instance with appropriate headers set."

Answer (score 3):

Return in CakePHP 3 application is used when you want to redirect to other pages or we can say actions/methods of other controllers or even if you want to redirect to 3rd Party Links like you have specified :-

```
return $this->redirect('/orders/thanks');
return $this->redirect('http://www.example.com');
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'thanks']);
```

And if you want to redirect to other method in the same controller then you can leave the return and use setAction as below but here URL will remain the same.

```
$this->setAction('thanks');
```

Return is better approach and URL will redirect if you use below code.

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'thanks']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#response)

> Response provides an interface to wrap the common response-related tasks such as:
>   Sending headers for redirects.

and [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages)

> You should return the response instance from your action to prevent view rendering and let the dispatcher handle actual redirection.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using route name then use this-

```
    $this->redirect(['_name' => 'view-details']);
```

you are using route then use this-

```
$this->redirect('/page/view-details');
```

and last option is this

```
$this->redirect(['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view']);
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

if you are use route name in view file then this use-

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

echo Router::url(['_name' => 'view-details']);

echo Router::url(['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => 15]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp, 3.6 to go to specific view/page Use  $this->render('filename');

like below

public function search()
    {

```
    $this->render(); 
            $this->render('profile'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off Autorendering

since cakephp methods by default want to end with a redirect to a CTP file

use `$this->autoRender = false`
inside you function